# Retrieving data on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to find out what are the companies/businesses around my area of interest. Is there any way that I can download these data (addresses, names) of the companies through google maps?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the google maps' javascript places to do the job. You can use, for example, nearby search witch return you all markets near you. Then, you can specified some names, type of shops, if they are open now...

This is a simply nearby search:

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['store']
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search?hl=fr) is an example of nearby search provided by google.

You also can add the name of the place (the system return you some places with the name that you precise):

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['store'],
name: 'Zara'
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

You may consult the [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en#place_search_requests).

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

**Note,** it is not precise in your question but I use javascript.